# Problema al almacenar datos en localStorage y mostrarlos por pantalla

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets, local-storage

estaba realizando un proyecto web en netbeans con conexión a una base de datos usando xampp, utilizando archivos.jsp, procesando formularios utilizando servlets. Hay cierto contenido de la web que quiero almacenarlo en el localStorage para luego mostrarlo por pantalla dinámicamente.
Hasta hace nada me funcionaba sin ningún tipo de problema, pero ahora no me almacena datos en el localStorage, ni me muestra por pantalla el contenido de una función de tipo JavaScript no sé si es por la última actualización de chrome, o por qué debo tener yo algún error en el código...

Agradezco la ayuda, si ves que podrías conseguirme una solución a esto contáctame.

Adjunto captura de pantalla  de uno de los errores que me aparece en chrome.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso no es un error, y hasta donde yo entiendo no tiene nada que ver con el localstorage.

Comment: Por favor, adjunta un [repro] del problema. No se puede responder _a ciegas_ ni _adivinar_ el problema. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.